# How many instance(s) of @Autowired "prototype" bean is(are) created during the usage of a @Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, singleton

I have a `Manager`class annotated with `@Component`  and `@Scope`

```
@Component     
@Scope(value = "prototype")     
public class Manager {
   ...
}
```

So I expect a new instance of the `Manager` bean will be created each time the bean is requested.

Then I have an `Adapter` class which uses this `Manager` bean. To use it, I have two ways of Autowire: 1. on the property or 2. on the constructor:

```
@Component     
public class Adapter {
    @Autowired     
    Manager m_Manager;

    ...
}
```

Or

```
@Component     
public class Adapter {
    Manager m_manager;

    @Autowired     
    public Adapter(Manager manager) {
        m_manager = manager;
    }

    ...
}
```

Since the `Adaptor` class is a singleton bean, so both `@Autowire` the `Manager`on the property or on the constructor will only create one instance of the `Manager`? Meaning `Manager`bean is actually used as a singleton bean instead of prototype bean, right?

Comment: they are singletons. only one instance that is reused

Comment: Thanks @Stultuske, I know the `Adaptor` is singleton, but the `Manager` bean is not. So you mean even though the `Manager` bean is prototype, only one instance will be created?

Comment: Prototypes should indeed return a different instance. haven't used it myself, personally, since the need never has come up to do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Autowire behaves in the same way as ApplicationContext.getBean

It creates a prototype bean for each autowired instance. you can see that the prototype object in two singletons has a different identifier[image]

So each singleton has its own prototype instance. It doesn't have any difference if you do it with @Autowire in the constructor or field.
Do Autowire on constructor is just more convenient way to avoid annotation duplication.

P.S. To define scope is better to use

```java
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
```

Comment: Thanks! So you mean in my case, multiple `Manager` instances will be created?

Comment: If you have 1+ singletons that reference Manager - yes. Each singleton will create its own prototype. If Manager would be a singleton, each singleton will be referencing the same instance of Manager

Comment: In your case Adapter will create a Manager single instance, but if you'll create another bean (Adapter2) with Manager injection - it will create different instance of Manager

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any other injection points, where you inject a Manager instance, then you will only have one instance in the application context, that's correct.